# Error 5 in php script after website transfer

Tags: php, json, curl, migration, hosting

I have no idea what happened but I transferred our excisting wordpress website with a lot of custom php / curl / javascript / jquery code to another hosting provider since we needed more speed / bandwith.

I moved the website myself and everything works as it should, except the custom application we programmed within our wordpress environment.

When we try to submit a form, we get the following error into our console:

```
POST https://verifiedcryptogroup.com/member-area/api/create_user.php 500 ()
send @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:4
ajax @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:4
(anonymous) @ (index):2599
dispatch @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3
r.handle @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3
```

As you can see we get an internal server error (500), nothing more.

Is this a hosting provider issue?

here is the code below of 'create_user.php'

```
<?php
include('functions.php');

// First we get all the information from the fields we need to pass on to 
swiftdill.
$type       = $_POST['type'];
$email      = $_POST['email'];
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name  = $_POST['last_name'];
$title      = $_POST['title'];
$middle_name    = $_POST['middle_name'];
$maiden_name    = $_POST['maiden_name'];
$dob            = $_POST['dob'];
$gender         = $_POST['gender'];
$mobile         = $_POST['mobile'];
$nationality    = $_POST['nationality'];
$birth_country  = $_POST['birth_country'];

$line       = $_POST['line'];
$extra_line = $_POST['extra_line'];
$city       = $_POST['city'];
$state_or_province = $_POST['state_or_province'];
$postal_code= $_POST['postal_code'];
$country    = $_POST['country'];

$wp_id      = $_POST['wp_id'];

if(isset($type) && $type != '') {

$fields = array(
    'type'          => $type,
    'email'         => $email,
    'first_name'    => $first_name,
    'last_name'     => $last_name,
    'title'         => $title,
    'middle_name'   => $middle_name,
    'maiden_name'   => $maiden_name,
    'dob'           => $dob,
    'gender'        => $gender,
    'mobile'        => $mobile,
    'nationality'   => $nationality,
    'birth_country' => $birth_country,
    'addresses'     => [ array(
                        'type'      => 'PRIMARY',
                        'line'      => $line,
                        'extra_line'=> $extra_line,
                        'city'      => $city,
                        'state_or_province' => $state_or_province,
                        'postal_code'=> $postal_code,
                        'country'   => $country
    )]
);
$fields = json_encode($fields);

// Get the access token and make sure it's not empty
$newToken = getAccessToken($api_url);

// Check if the token is empty. If so: give a message and stop the script.
if (empty($newToken)) {
    echo '{ "error": "The token is invalid!" }';
    return;
} else {
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $api_url . "customers",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $fields,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "Authorization: Bearer $newToken",
            "Cache-Control: no-cache",
            "Content-Type: application/json",
            "Postman-Token: xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx"
        )
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    if ($err) {
        echo '{ "error": "cURL Error #:'  . $err . '" }';
    } else {
        $result = json_decode($response, true);
        if($result['id'] != '' && $result['email'] != '') {
            // De zojuist aangemaakte gebruiker wordt toegevoegd aan de eigen database
            $addCustomerId = addCustomerId($db, $wp_id, $result['id']);
            if($addCustomerId == 'success') {
                echo '{ "message": "success" }';
            } else {
                echo $response;
            }
        } else {
            echo $response;
        }
    }
}
}     else {
    echo '{ "error": "Type incorrect" }';
}
```

Comment: 500 errors can be everything. Try to look up some error logs from apache/nginx, php itself, maybe wordpress has some. There will probably be a fairly detailed error in one of them that matches your experienced behavior.

Comment: And trace your code, add prints, debug!

Comment: Already did. No errors or whatsoever in the error logs. . . Someone advice?

Comment: Have you checked that the PHP-curl extension is enabled on your new server ?

Answer (score 0):

> Fixing 500 Internal Server Error Problems on Your Own Site A 500
>   Internal Server Error on your own website requires a completely
>   different course of action. As we mentioned above, most 500 errors are
>   server-side errors, meaning it's likely your problem to fix if it's
>   your website.
>
> There are lots of reasons why your site might be serving a 500 Error
>   to your users, but these are the most common:
>
> A Permissions Error. In most cases, a 500 Internal Server Error is due
>   to an incorrect permission on one or more files or folders. In most of
>   those cases, an incorrect permission on a PHP and CGI script is to
>   blame. These should usually be set at 0755 (-rwxr-xr-x). A PHP
>   Timeout. If your script connects to external resources and those
>   resources timeout, an HTTP 500 error can occur. Timeout rules, or
>   better error handling in your script, should help if this is the cause
>   of the 500 error. A Coding Error in .htaccess. While not as common, be
>   sure to check that your site's .htaccess file is properly structured.
>   If you're running WordPress, Joomla, or another content management or
>   CMS system, be sure to search their support centers for more specific
>   help troubleshooting a 500 Internal Server Error.
>
> If you're not using an off-the-shelf content management tool, your web
>   hosting provider, like InMotion, Dreamhost, 1&1, etc., probably has
>   some 500 Error help that might be more specific to your situation.

Source:
https://www.lifewire.com/500-internal-server-error-explained-2622938

Comment: Checked my error logs and such, no strange things there.